# Pytest-Variables: how to use them without funcarg?

Tags: unit-testing, class, variables, pytest, fixtures

I wanna pass a json file for testbed definition to pytest.

My testcases are implemented inside a unittest class and need to use the json file send via pytest cli.

I tried to use pytest-variable to pass a json to pytest. Then I want to use the json as a dictionary inside my tests.

To be clearer, my test is launched with this command

pytest -s --variables ../testbeds/testbed_SQA_252.json TC_1418.py

I know unittest cannot accept external arguments but will be very useful a technique to unlock this constraint.

**CASE 1 -- test implemented as functions --->OK**

```
def test_variables(variables):
     print(variables)
```

in this case the ouput is correct and the json is printed in the CLI

**CASE 2-- test implemented as Unittest Class--->KO**

```
class TC_1418(unittest.TestCase):
     def setUp(self, variables):
        print (variables)
        ....other functions
```

I obtain the following error:

TypeError: setUp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'variables'

Any Idea?

Comment: I tried also creating a class different than unittest but the problem is the same: cannot pass parameter inside a class.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from **mixing up concepts** of `pytest` (e.g. injection of fixtures like `variables`) with concepts of `unittest.TestCase`. While pytest supports running tests based on `unittest`, I'm afraid that injection of plugins' fixtures into test methods is [not supported](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses).

There is a workaround though that takes advantage of fixtures being injected into other fixtures and [making custom fixtures available](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#mixing-pytest-fixtures-into-unittest-testcase-subclasses-using-marks) in `unittest.TestCase` with `@pytest.mark.usefixtures` decorator:

```py
# TC_1418.py

import pytest
import unittest


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def variables_injector(request, variables):
    request.cls.variables = variables


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("variables_injector")
class Test1418(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        print(self.variables)
```

**Notice that the name of the class starts with `Test` so as to follow [conventions for test discovery](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).**

If you don't want to go into this travesty, I propose you rather fully embrace Pytest and make your life easier with simple test functions that you have already discovered or properly structured test classes:

```py
# TC_1418.py

class Test1418:
    def test_something(self, variables):
        print(variables)
```

Comment: Thank You. My purpose is to use the setup/teardown methods used by unittest.